# What is the difference in these two program

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-tree

I was making a binary tree program and this program worked

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};



void insert( node **rootnode , int value) {

    node* newnode = *rootnode;

    if ( newnode == NULL ) {
        newnode = new node;
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->data  = value;
        *rootnode = newnode; // this was missing!
    }
    else if ( value < newnode->data ){
        insert( &newnode->left , value );
    }
    else if ( value > newnode->data  ){
        insert ( &newnode->right , value );
    }


}

void inorder ( node *root ){
    if ( root == NULL ){
        return;
    }
    else{
        inorder( root->left );
        cout << root->data << endl;
        inorder( root->right );
    }
}




int main(){

    node* root = NULL;

    insert ( &root , 4);
    insert ( &root , 5);
    insert ( &root , 2 );
    insert( &root , 10 );
    insert( &root , 1 );

    //cout << root->data << endl;
    inorder( root );

}
```

Now i tried to make this without passing the reference of root node ... But it not working ... I was not able to find why ..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};



void insert( node *rootnode , int value) {

    node* newnode = rootnode;

    if ( newnode == NULL ) {
        newnode = new node;
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->data  = value;
        rootnode = newnode; // this was missing!
    }
    else if ( value < newnode->data ){
        insert( newnode->left , value );
    }
    else if ( value > newnode->data  ){
        insert ( newnode->right , value );
    }


}

void inorder ( node *root ){
    if ( root == NULL ){
        return;
    }
    else{
        inorder( root->left );
        cout << root->data << endl;
        inorder( root->right );
    }
}




int main(){

    node* root = NULL;

    insert ( root , 4);
    insert ( root , 5);
    insert ( root , 2 );
    insert( root , 10 );
    insert( root , 1 );

    //cout << root->data << endl;
    inorder( root );

}
```

The second program just gave blank output... I think the root node is not updating .. But i don'nt know why....

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function parameters are local variables of the function. They get copies of the values of the corresponding arguments.

You can imagine the following function declaration

```
void insert( node *rootnode , int value);
```

and its call

```
insert ( root , 4);
```

the following way

```
void insert( /*node *rootnode , int value*/)
{
    node *rootnode = root;
    int value = 4;
    //...
```

After exiting the function these local variables will be destroyed. The original value of varibale `root` will not be changed because the function deals with a copy of `root`.

So if you want to change any object passed to a function within the function you need to pass it by reference in the C meaning or in the C++ meaning.

That is in C you pass a pointer to the object. In C++ you can use the same method or declare the corresonding parameter as reference.

So in C the function declaration can look like

```
void insert( node **rootnode , int value) ;
```

while in C++ it can look either like above or the following way

```
void insert( node * &rootnode , int value) ;
```